# How to upload a video to parse server?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, parse-platform

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri selected = data.getData();
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(selected));
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        for (int readnum; (readnum = fis.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readnum);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    ParseFile parseFile =new ParseFile("video.mp4",bytes);
    ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("video2");
    parseObject.put("video2", parseFile);
    parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "video has been uploaded successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "sorry we could't upload the video ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my current code. I managed to access the phone gallery and then I convert the video to byte array to be able to upload it to Parse but i guess the problem is that any video i choose returns null i access the gallery using this code :

public class userlist extends AppCompatActivity {
public void getphoto() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

here is my stack trace

java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/video/media/14146 (No such file or directory)

2020-07-05 17:28:03.965 31930-31930/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.starter.userlist.onActivityResult(userlist.java:85)

2020-07-05 17:28:03.967 31930-31930/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.starter.userlist.onActivityResult(userlist.java:92)

2020-07-05 17:28:03.981 31930-32065/com.parse.starter W/System: Ignoring header Content-Type because its value was null.

Comment: Could you format your code and add some more description of what the code does?

Comment: i added more details hope that my question become clearer

Comment: Hi Mohamed. Could you please add stacktrace to your question, so that we could see in which line of your code an NPE is thrown? The better you make your question, the easier it gets for someone to answer it (it's a kind of "help us help you"). Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i added all the stack trace it seems that the video i choose always returns null so the array bytes always ends up empty i don't know why the video returns null i use this code to get access to gallery and then i choose the video                                                              
     public void getVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

Comment: GreenMarker if you know any code to upload a video to parse that will be so helpful thanks in advance